# Efficient query in Cypher (as in Neo4J) to find union of shortest paths

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, networkx

I'm looking for an efficient Cypher query to find the subgraph defined on a subset of nodes from a graph, defined as the union of shortest paths between nodes in that subset.

Currently, what I have is:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
gdb = GraphDatabase.driver(address)
with gdb.session() as session:


    query = "MATCH path=shortestPath((n1)-[*1..{0}]->(n2)) ".format(max_path_length)
    query += "where n1.Name in {0} and c2.Name in {0} and n1.Name<>n2.Name ".format(list(nodes))
    query += "return rels(path)"

    paths = list(session.run(query).data())

edges = set().union(*(set(path['rels(path)']) for path in paths))
graph = nx.Graph(list(edges))
```

Now, this code works - but is inefficient, calculating the shortest path between any two nodes separately, while many of the paths intersect (as one can expect in a realistic use-case of a "sub-graph").

I don't know an efficient algorithm to calculate this; is there one - implemented in Cypher?

Related questions:
[Extract subgraph from Neo4j graph with Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571966/extract-subgraph-from-neo4j-graph-with-cypher) shows how to save a bit in syntax by defining the list of nodes with a "WITH" statement, but it have not said to improve performance (maybe it is not possible).
[Extract subgraph in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101789/extract-subgraph-in-neo4j?rq=1) deals with the subgraph around a single source - if it applies to my case I don't quite understand how (will accept an answer that explains how that answers there help my case)

EDITED: I'd also accept a solution that returns the (or a) minimal subgraph that contains the given nodes; I didn't ask about it because it looked like a harder question, and I didn't have a code sample for it. If I'm wrong and it's actually easier, I'd accept that.

Comment: isn't it true that any edge is on some "shortest path"? that is, every edge is the shortest path between its adjacent nodes. so your graph is just the induced subgraph by the given node list. am I missing something?

Comment: I'm looking for edges in shortest paths between nodes from a given subset

Comment: Can you explain why you want to find shortest path between every pair of nodes? I feel you have to approach the problem differently. Solutions like Minimum Weight Spanning Tree, or even different traversal algorithms might be more helpful.

Comment: @NonameCurious Is finding the minimum weight spanning tree shorter/easier in Neo4j/Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [all pairs shortest path](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/all-pairs-shortest-path) and [minimum weight spanning tree](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/minimum-weight-spanning-tree/) algorithms available from the Neo4j graph algorithms library? All pairs shortest path returns the distance for each pair of nodes, not the path, so it might not meet your need.

Comment: If the former returns distances, and not a graph structure, it is indeed not what I'm looking for. And as for the latter, if I understand correctly it takes a single node as a source and finds all reachable nodes, which is also not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You are correct on both counts, so we'll have to keep thinking. 
On your edit, you said you would accept a minimal subgraph that contains the selected noes. Does that subgraph need to be a single connected component?

Comment: If possible, yes. If not, the disjoint set of nodes is a (trivial) solution. But I recognize that the solution might not be a single connected component, if the original graph is not connected.

Comment: Let's say that if the original graph is connected, I expect the solution to also be.