# Order the result by the number of relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, relationship, directed-graph

I have a directed multigraph. With this query I tried to find all the nodes that is connected to node with the `uuid` n1_34

```
MATCH (n1:Node{uuid: "n1_34"}) -[r]- (n2:Node) RETURN n2, r
```

This will give me a list of `n2` (n1_1187, n2_2280, n2_1834, n2_932 and n2_722) and their relationships among themselves which are exactly what I need.

[Nodes n1_1187, n2_2280, n2_1834, n2_932 and n2_722 are connected to the node n1_34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q88qp.png)

Now I need to order them based on the relationship it has within this subgraph. So for example, n1_1187 should be on top with 4 relationships while the others have 1 relationship.

I followed this post: [Extract subgraph from Neo4j graph with Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571966/extract-subgraph-from-neo4j-graph-with-cypher) but it gives me the same result as the query above. I also tried to return `count(r)` but it gives me 1 since it counts all unique relationships not the relationships with a common source/target.

Usually with networkx I can copy this result into a subgraph then count the relationships of each node. Can I do that with neo4j without modifying the current graph? How?

Please help. Or is there other way?

Comment: What do you mean by "within this subgraph"? Do you only want to count the relationships between the set of `n2` nodes returned by your `MATCH`? (We already know that each `n2` has a relationship to `n1`, so that does not need to be included in the counts.)

Comment: correct. I made some mistakes when writing the question. I expect the query to return n1_1187 on the top of the list because it has 4 relationships with the other n2 nodes. Then followed by the rest of the n2 nodes with 1 relationship. "This subgraph" is the subgraph I showed in the pictures (Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post image directly because I am new and short of reputation). I come up with the correct query . See the comment below the Darren Hicks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet will recreate your graph for testing purposes:

```
WITH ['n1_34,n1_1187','n1_34,n2_2280','n1_34,n2_1834','n1_34,n2_722',    'n1_34,n2_932','n1_1187,n2_2280','n1_1187,n2_932','n1_1187,n2_1834',       'n1_1187,n2_722'] AS node_relationships
UNWIND node_relationships as relationship
with split(relationship, ",") as nodes
merge(n1:Node{label:nodes[0]})
merge(n2:Node{label:nodes[1]})
merge(n1)-[:LINK]-(n2)
```

Once that is run, the graph I'm working with looks like:

[image]

Then this CQL will select the nodes in the subgraph and then subsequently count up each of their respective associated links, but only to other nodes existing already in the subgraph:

```
match(n1:Node{label:'n1_34'})-[:LINK]-(n2:Node)
with collect(distinct(n2)) as subgraph_nodes
unwind subgraph_nodes as subgraph_node
match(subgraph_node)-[r:LINK]-(n3:Node)
where n3 in subgraph_nodes
return subgraph_node.label, count(r) order by count(r) DESC
```

Running the above yields the following result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found the quert days ago, several hours worth of testing and reading after posting this. This is the query I came up with:

`
MATCH (n1:Node {uuid: "n1_34"}) -- (n2:Node)
MATCH (n1) -- () -[r]- (n2)
RETURN n2, count(r)  ORDER BY count(r) DESC
`

Thank you again. I am not familiar with the unwind and collect operation but your solution help with my understanding on usage of such operations.

Answer (score 0):

This query should do what you need :

```
MATCH (n1:Node{uuid: "n1_34"})-[r]-(n2:Node)
RETURN n1, n2, count(*) AS freq
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Comment: No, this gives me all the relationships that n2 nodes have within the entire graph, not the relationships among themselves within the subgraph. See the comment under Darren Hicks solution for the actual query that I use.

Answer (score 0):

Using [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) to assess the efficiency of some of the existing solutions using @DarrenHick's sample data, the following is the most efficient one I have found, needing only 84 DB hits:

```
MATCH (n1:Node{label:'n1_34'})-[:LINK]-(n2:Node)
WITH COLLECT(n2) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS n
RETURN n, SIZE([(n)-[:LINK]-(n3) WHERE n3 IN nodes | null]) AS cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Darren's solution (adjusted to return `subgraph_node` instead of `subgraph_node.label`, for parity) requires 92 DB hits.

@LuckyChandrautama's own solution (provided in a comment to Darren's answer, and adjusted to match Darren's sample data), uses 122 DB hits.

This shows the importance of using PROFILE to assess the performance of different Cypher solutions against the actual data. You should try doing that with your actual data to see which one works best for you.

Comment: wow thank you so much. I am not aware with such command.